# check value in object array - vuejs

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to check the following value in my vue project:

[image]

I tried something like:

```
return this.model.status.tasks.state === 'FAILED';
```

or:

```
return this.model.status.tasks.state.includes('FAILED');
```

but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your tasks is an array so you need index before reaching state like

```
this.model.status.tasks[0].state
```

Comment: how can I return `true` if the state is `FAILED`?

Comment: @justin return this.model.status.tasks[0].state === 'FAILED';